# What will be the best approach, apply function or for loop in pandas dataframe for replacing null values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, apply, missing-data

I have a dataset with 100000 records for which I need to replace null values based on multiple columns.
I have tried with two approach:

```
#First Approach    
# Missing value treatment
    start_time = time.time()
    
    data['date_of_last_rech_data_6'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_6','total_rech_data_6','max_rech_data_6']))) else x['date_of_last_rech_data_6'], axis = 1)
    data['total_rech_data_6'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_6','total_rech_data_6','max_rech_data_6']))) else x['total_rech_data_6'], axis = 1)
    data['max_rech_data_6'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_6','total_rech_data_6','max_rech_data_6']))) else x['max_rech_data_6'], axis = 1)
    
    data['date_of_last_rech_data_7'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_7','total_rech_data_7','max_rech_data_7']))) else x['date_of_last_rech_data_7'], axis = 1)
    data['total_rech_data_7'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_7','total_rech_data_7','max_rech_data_7']))) else x['total_rech_data_7'], axis = 1)
    data['max_rech_data_7'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_7','total_rech_data_7','max_rech_data_7']))) else x['max_rech_data_7'], axis = 1)
    
    data['date_of_last_rech_data_8'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_8','total_rech_data_8','max_rech_data_8']))) else x['date_of_last_rech_data_8'], axis = 1)
    data['total_rech_data_8'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_8','total_rech_data_8','max_rech_data_8']))) else x['total_rech_data_8'], axis = 1)
    data['max_rech_data_8'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_8','total_rech_data_8','max_rech_data_8']))) else x['max_rech_data_8'], axis = 1)
    
    data['date_of_last_rech_data_9'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_9','total_rech_data_9','max_rech_data_9']))) else x['date_of_last_rech_data_9'], axis = 1)
    data['total_rech_data_9'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_9','total_rech_data_9','max_rech_data_9']))) else x['total_rech_data_9'], axis = 1)
    data['max_rech_data_9'] = data.apply(lambda x: 0 if(np.all(pd.isnull(['date_of_last_rech_data_9','total_rech_data_9','max_rech_data_9']))) else x['max_rech_data_9'], axis = 1)
    
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time-start_time)
```

Time taken by this snippet is 152.52092480659485.

```
#Second Approach
start_time = time.time()

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    # Missing value treatment for the month of June
    if pd.isnull((data['date_of_last_rech_data_6'][i]) and (data['total_rech_data_6'][i]) and (data['max_rech_data_6'][i]) ):
        data['date_of_last_rech_data_6'][i]=0
        data['total_rech_data_6'][i]=0
        data['max_rech_data_6'][i]=0 
    # Missing value treatment for the month of July
    if pd.isnull((data['date_of_last_rech_data_7'][i]) and (data['total_rech_data_7'][i]) and (data['max_rech_data_7'][i]) ):
        data['date_of_last_rech_data_7'][i]=0
        data['total_rech_data_7'][i]=0
        data['max_rech_data_7'][i]=0
    # Missing value treatment for the month of August
    if pd.isnull((data['date_of_last_rech_data_8'][i]) and (data['total_rech_data_8'][i]) and (data['max_rech_data_8'][i]) ):
        data['date_of_last_rech_data_8'][i]=0
        data['total_rech_data_8'][i]=0
        data['max_rech_data_8'][i]=0 
    # Missing value treatment for the month of September
    if pd.isnull((data['date_of_last_rech_data_9'][i]) and (data['total_rech_data_9'][i]) and (data['max_rech_data_9'][i]) ):
        data['date_of_last_rech_data_9'][i]=0
        data['total_rech_data_9'][i]=0
        data['max_rech_data_9'][i]=0  
        
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

Time taken by this code 223.60794281959534. But this code sometime runs and sometime just hangs and stops the kernel.

Is there any other best approach to do this?

Comment: That's a lot of repeated code. On first glance, `data['max_rech_data_7'][i]=0` is chained indexing and is unlikely to work/update your `data`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to replace the null values if date_of_last_rech_data_* , total_rech_data_* and max_rech_data_* data are null then replacing it with 0. I am doing this for month 6,7,8,9.

Comment: can you provide small segment of your data along with how your output should look like ? may be we can optimize this code a little bit....

Comment: @k33da_the_bug I am just treating missing values for data cleaning purpose. dataset has about 300 columns which I can not put here. But I can provide you with datatypes. ('date_of_last_rech_data_6':date type, 'total_rech_data_6':float,'max_rech_data_7':float). This data is from telecom churn case study.